# JavaScript string search

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, search

I'm trying to search a string for any word of another string with javaScript. Let's say I have the following string that I want to search in:

```
"Oxford Street 100 London"
```

And my search term is like this:

```
"oxford london"
```

The above searchterm should give me a match since `oxford` and `london` is a part of the string to search in.

I have tried `str.indexOf("oxford london") !== -1` but that doesn't work since it's not a combined word in the string to search in.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Should it match because both the words are in it, or would 1 do - what if you searched for "oxford manchester"?

Comment: searching for "oxford manchester" should also give a match since the string contains "oxford" :-)

Comment: `new RegExp("oxford london".split(/\W+/).join("|"), 'i')` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the search terms by a space and search for each (case inensitively, I presume)

```
var terms = terms.split(' '),
    match = terms.every(function (term) {
        return str.toLowerCase.indexOf(term) > -1;
    });
```

Comment: `forEach`? Do you mean `filter`?

Comment: Use `.every` instead of trying to filter with `forEach` (which doesn't even work)

Comment: Yes I meant filter, but every is even better

Comment: You should use `some` instead of `every`. Now its only true if all keys are found, while [the OP said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121556/javascript-string-search#comment23026352_16121556) that at least one key must be found.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a simple [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html):

```
if("London, Oxford street".match(new RegExp("oxford london".split(/\W+/).join("|"), 'i'))) {
    alert("found");   
}
```

Comment: That's not using the search string `"oxford london"` though.

Comment: also, does not match "London, Oxford street"

Comment: Yup you guys were right, updated it with the code stolen from user2264587.

Comment: Hello, tried it with `if("London,Oford street"...` and it also reported "found". Should be also somehow fixed.

Comment: Use `regex.test(str)` instead of `str.match(regex) !== null`

Answer (score 1):

```
mystring = "Oxford Street 100 London"
search = "oxford london"
// split search string, by space, or by another delimiter if you like
terms = search.split(" ")
matches = false
// loop through all terms, assuming that matches is true if no negative comparisons are made
for(i=0; i< terms.length; i++){
  // make sure you lowercase both search string, and comparison string
  if(mystring.toLowerCase().indexOf(terms[i].toLowerCase())){
    matches = true
  }
}
// matches is true if any terms are found, and false if no term is found
```

Comment: @Archer Please do not add such significant modifications to a post without the original author's consent.

Comment: @RobW It's now wrong - no problem.  I'll leave it the way you prefer :)

Comment: @RobW I expect it was by accident, I was adding stuff at the same time, so he probably did not know he was deleting my additions

Comment: @Archer, I could be wrong, but I don't think it is wrong. Matches starts off being assumed to be true - and if any of the terms are compared, and don't match, it turns to false. Seems like good logic to me.

Comment: It needs to match if either of the words are found - not both ;)

Comment: @Archer I see, it was not in the question, but in the comments.

Comment: @Archer I updated, I think this works now - got there in the end :)

Comment: Yeah, I *think* that's what he's after too.  +1 from me :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var str = "Oxford Street 100 London";
var terms = "oxford london";
terms = terms.replace(" ", "|");          // "oxford|london"
var find = new RegExp(terms, "g");        // /oxford|london/g
alert(str.toLowerCase().match(find));     // ["oxford", "london"]
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJjZN/).